# How to update a page in Confluence 5.5.1 via rest call

Tags: java, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I can find the latest API from Atlassian.

https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/5.5.3/#d2e120

I can see that I should be able to update a page via the call "/content/{id}" PUT.

But when I try to PUT I just get a 500 back from the server.
If I try a simple example like this...

Example code for trying to update a page.

```
String json = 
    "   {                                                          "+
    "       \"body\":{                                             "+
    "           \"view\":{                                         "+
    "               \"value\":\"<p>main updated</p>\",              "+
    "           }                                                  "+
    "         }                                                    "+
    "   }                                                          ";

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://x.x.x.x/rest/api/content/8226411?os_username=j.p@p.com&os_password=xxx");

        webResource.setProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").put(ClientResponse.class, json);

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... statusCode ["+response.getStatus()+"]");
        System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
```

I still get a 500 error back.

```
Output from Server .... statusCode [500]
{"statusCode":500,"message":"javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: null"}
```

Can someone please give me some advice.

Below is the stacktrace from the Confluence log files...

```
2014-07-02 10:15:57,856 WARN [http-bio-80-exec-15274] [atlassian.confluence.cache.TransactionalCacheFactory] warning Transactional cache update outside transaction. All updates to this cache should be performed from a thread with a valid transaction context.
2014-07-02 10:15:57,856 ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-15274] [rest.api.model.ExceptionConverter] convertServiceException No status code found for exception, converting to internal server error : 
 -- url: /rest/api/content/8226411 | userName: j.p@p.com
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
                at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:178)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
                at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:73)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilterInternal(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:26)
                at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilter(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:40)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:25)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:37)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.arsenale.plugins.lockpoint.LifecycleFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:53)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.plugins.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:65)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:36)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:60)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:92)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:56)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
                at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.util.profiling.ProfilingPageFilter.doFilter(ProfilingPageFilter.java:44)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.cache.TransactionalCacheFactoryCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionalCacheFactoryCleanupFilter.java:68)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.ServletContextThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ServletContextThreadLocalFilter.java:21)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.util.LoggingContextFilter.doFilter(LoggingContextFilter.java:40)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.util.UserNameHeaderFilter.doFilter(UserNameHeaderFilter.java:26)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceTimeoutFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceTimeoutFilter.java:63)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:211)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceSecurityFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceSecurityFilter.java:27)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ThreadLocalCacheFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCacheFilter.java:28)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:100)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.util.AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.doFilter(AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.java:34)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:61)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:44)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.util.ClusterHeaderFilter.doFilter(ClusterHeaderFilter.java:42)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:170)
                at com.atlassian.spring.filter.FlushingSpringSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(FlushingSpringSessionInViewFilter.java:29)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.util.profiling.filters.ProfilingFilter.doFilter(ProfilingFilter.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:80)
                at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:33)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceTimingFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceTimingFilter.java:79)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.extra.webdav.servlet.filter.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(ReverseProxyFilter.java:427)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.extra.webdav.servlet.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:34)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.validateparam.RequestParamValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestParamValidationFilter.java:58)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.TranslationModeFilter.doFilter(TranslationModeFilter.java:43)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.servlet.filter.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:71)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.LanguageExtractionFilter.doFilter(LanguageExtractionFilter.java:53)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.util.RequestCacheThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheThreadLocalFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ResponseOutputStreamFilter.doFilter(ResponseOutputStreamFilter.java:25)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.HeaderSanitisingFilter.doFilter(HeaderSanitisingFilter.java:44)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.servlet.FourOhFourErrorLoggingFilter.doFilter(FourOhFourErrorLoggingFilter.java:65)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:50)
                at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

---

payload in Wireshark that does NOT work...

PUT /rest/api/content/?os_username=j.p@com&os_password=patterns HTTP/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application-json
User-Agent: Java/1.7
Host: x.x.x.x
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 141

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I need to give credit to Joseph Clark of Atlassian for his answer...

Here's some example code I wrote which demonstrates how to PUT a new version of a Page using the Confluence REST API:

https://bitbucket.org/jaysee00/confluence-rest-api-example/src/master/src/main/java/com/atlassian/api/examples/Main.java

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/312039/how-to-update-a-page-in-confluence-5-5-3-via-rest-call

I'll put the Main.java code here to keep the answer in one place.

```
public class Main
{
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://x.x.x.x/";
    private static final String USERNAME = "jeff@p.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "pat";
    private static final String ENCODING = "utf-8";

    private static String getContentRestUrl(final Long contentId, final String[] expansions) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        final String expand = URLEncoder.encode(StringUtils.join(expansions, ","), ENCODING);

        return String.format("%s/rest/api/content/%s?expand=%s&os_authType=basic&os_username=%s&os_password=%s", BASE_URL, contentId, expand, URLEncoder.encode(USERNAME, ENCODING), URLEncoder.encode(PASSWORD, ENCODING));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final long pageId = 8226411;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Get current page version
        String pageObj = null;
        HttpEntity pageEntity = null;
        try
        {
            HttpGet getPageRequest = new HttpGet(getContentRestUrl(pageId, new String[] {"body.storage", "version"}));
            HttpResponse getPageResponse = client.execute(getPageRequest);
            pageEntity = getPageResponse.getEntity();

            pageObj = IOUtils.toString(pageEntity.getContent());

            System.out.println("Get Page Request returned " + getPageResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(pageObj);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pageEntity != null)
            {
                EntityUtils.consume(pageEntity);
            }
        }

        // Parse response into JSON
        JSONObject page = new JSONObject(pageObj);

        // Update page
        // The updated value must be Confluence Storage Format (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Storage+Format), NOT HTML.
        page.getJSONObject("body").getJSONObject("storage").put("value", "hello, world");

        int currentVersion = page.getJSONObject("version").getInt("number");
        page.getJSONObject("version").put("number", currentVersion + 1);

        // Send update request
        HttpEntity putPageEntity = null;

        try
        {
            HttpPut putPageRequest = new HttpPut(getContentRestUrl(pageId, new String[]{}));

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(page.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            putPageRequest.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse putPageResponse = client.execute(putPageRequest);
            putPageEntity = putPageResponse.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Put Page Request returned " + putPageResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(putPageEntity.getContent()));
        }
        finally
        {
            EntityUtils.consume(putPageEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this works great running locally (mac). But on linux boxes I get the following error:  09:45:43,718 [main] DEBUG BasicClientConnectionManager:201 - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@1e3c1a28
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)         Do you have an examples that support SSL or certs???

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you are trying to create a page, but the Confluence REST API requires a [POST](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/5.5.1/#d2e477) for creating new content, not a [PUT](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/5.5.1/#d2e495) (which is for updating existing content).

In other words, change the request method to POST, and make sure that you have not specified a content ID in the URL. ie. use "x.x.x.x/rest/api/content" and not "x.x.x.x/rest/api/content/8226411"

If that doesn't work, also look at your existing PUT (-> POST) code and verify that you have supplied the full set of headers included in my 'curl' example on the answer to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523705/how-to-create-new-page-in-confluence-using-their-rest-api/23526357#23526357).

Comment: you are correct, I should have used "update" not "create" in my question. In either case it results in a 500 error.

Comment: OK. Can you post your PUT code then? Also, what is in the body of the 500 error response? Atlassian apps often use that indicate what went wrong with the API call.

Comment: I've added the example code and the response body. thanks for taking to the time to look over this.

Comment: That's a Jersey exception saying that, as far as I can tell, it could not match the URL to a supported request method and type. But wait, I'm confused again: are you updating content or creating? If updating, to start with, you're missing the content ID at the end of the URL here: `WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://x.x.x.x/rest/api/content?os_username=j.p@pcom&os_password=xxx");` and there is no PUT method supported at that endpoint. It should be /rest/api/content/### where the ### corresponds to the content ID to update. And you also need to be doing a put() instead of post().

Comment: ok, I'm trying to do a PUT/UPDATE in this case, I've tried a CREATE/POST (with no {id}) but that gives the same error.

Comment: the content {id} ive got seems correct since the GET will return the document and is the same id shown when I edit the page in the URL.

Comment: I don't recall offhand what the required representation is for the PUT, so I can only give you guidance on the POST/CREATE operation. Does the curl command from my [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523705/how-to-create-new-page-in-confluence-using-their-rest-api/23526357#23526357) work? If so, can you use tcpdump to grab a packet dump while running your Java app too and see what is different?

Comment: I am also unclear about the current data you are posting, but note that there is a stray comma at the end of this line in the original question: `\"value\":\"<p>main updated</p>\",   `

Comment: I'm unsure what the payload should be, and you are correct about the extra comma, removing it makes no difference. Thanks again for the taking the time to respond

Comment: I'll add example payloads above to show it not working in Java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56785/discussion-between-scott-dudley-and-jeff-porter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new version number to your update call. I had exactly the same problem until I started adding that. Note the last part of this:

{"id":"4096014","type":"page","title":"NC-1","space":{"key":"OTF"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"Mike Testing an update","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":"3"}}