# How to create a new page in Confluence using jQuery and their REST API?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest, confluence

I have been looking for a pure HTML and jQuery example of how to create a page in Confluence using their REST API.  I found the following examples, but neither of them are working for me:

- https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+REST+API+Examples
- https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Using+the+REST+APIs+-+Prototype+Only
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/167281/jira-rest-api-with-jquery
- https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/

**Example A**

```
var username = "admin";
var password = "admin";
var jsondata = {"type":"page",
"title":"My Test Page",
"space":{"key":"TST"},
"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}};

$.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username+ ":" + password)
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
    success: function (){
        console.log('Page saved!');
    },
    error : function(xhr, errorText){
        console.log('Error '+ xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Example B**

```
var jsondata = {"type":"page",
"title":"My Test Page",
"space":{"key":"TEST"},
"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}

$.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4= " );
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
    success: function (){
        console.log('Page saved!');
    }
});
```

**My Code**

```
var data = {
      type: "page",
      title: "New Page",
      space: {
            key: "TST"
      },
      body: {
            storage: {
                  value: "<p>This is a new page</p>",
                  representation: "storage"
            }
      }
};

var link = 'http://confluence.mysite.com:80/rest/api/content/';

$.ajax({
      url: link,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      crossDomain: true,
      username: user.username,
      password: user.password,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (result) {
            alert('Data saved!');
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('Status: ' + status + '\n' +
                   'Error: ' + error);
      }
});
```

I tried the following solution (***above***), but it seems I am having trouble authenticating against Confluence.  I checked the permissions, and I am a member of Confluence's administrative group.  The GET command appears to work, however with the POST, I keep getting:

```
({"statusCode":403,"message":"You're not allowed to view that space, or it does not exist."})
```

I have found similar questions posted, yet none of them have a working solution.  Most of the resources appear to be written for python.

- [How to create new page in Confluence using their REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523705/how-to-create-new-page-in-confluence-using-their-rest-api)
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/149561/simple-confluence-rest-api-usage-what-am-i-missing

Is there another API solution which would prove to be better?  I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks again @mansilladev.  With your help, I was able to find the solution.  Instead of using the following methods:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4= " );
}
```

or

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
}
```

Using the **xhrFields** option, with **username** & **password**, appears to execute a successful request.

**My Solution**

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    username: user.username,
    password: user.password,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    xhrFields: {
            "withCredentials": true
    },
    success: function (result) {
            alert('Data saved!');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + ' | ' + error);
    }
});
```