# Confluence Rest API: Can I create a page by space and parent?

Tags: c#, rest, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Im just facing the fact, that i want to create a page in a certain space as a child of a defined parent.

Is there a possibility to do this by these means?
I didn't find it yet.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create new page in Confluence using their REST API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523705/how-to-create-new-page-in-confluence-using-their-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the documentation:
[Create a new page as a child of another page](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Createanewpageasachildofanotherpage)

This is curl, but should be the similar in C#

Answer (score 0):

[Create a new page as a child of another page](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Createanewpageasachildofanotherpage)

This is a REST API. Because the REST API is based on open standards, you can use any web development language to access the API.

In C#, you could use one of the following options:

- HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse
- WebClient
- HttpClient (available from .NET 4.5 on)

I'd highly recommend using the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, as it's engineered to be much better (from a usability standpoint) than the former two.

Answer (score 0):

all the parts you'll need:

the createPage function
the http post function
the dumb class to make the sample json qualified.
the sample json & base url

```
internal static string createAPage(string space, string title, string body, string objectType, int ancestorId = -1)
        {
            string json = string.Empty;
            try
            {

                CreateContentWithParentJson createContentWithParentJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateContentWithParentJson>(_jsonCreatePageWithParentSample);
                createContentWithParentJson.space.key = space;
                createContentWithParentJson.title = title;
                body = body.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                createContentWithParentJson.body.storage.value = "<p>" + body + "</p>";
                Ancestor a = new Ancestor();
                a.id = ancestorId;
                createContentWithParentJson.ancestors = new List<Ancestor>();
                createContentWithParentJson.ancestors.Add(a);
                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createContentWithParentJson, Utils.getJsonSettings());

        }
        catch (Exception) {  // handle exception 
        }
        return Utils.contentPost(json, _baseUrl);

    }


  internal static string contentPost(string postData, string url, string method = "POST")
        {
            string encodedCred = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(ConfAPI._confUser + ":" + ConfAPI._confPass));
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCred);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");
            request.Method = method;
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            // request.KeepAlive = false;
            if (postData != null)
            {
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
            WebResponse response;

            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                return e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace.ToString();
            }

            var responsestring = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return responsestring;
        }

  public class CreateContentWithParentJson
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<Ancestor> ancestors { get; set; }
        public Space space { get; set; }
        public Body body { get; set; }
    }

 internal static string _baseUrl = "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content";
 internal static string _jsonCreatePageWithParentSample = @"{'type':'page','title':'new page', 'ancestors':[{'id':456}], 'space':{'key':'TST'},'body':{'storage':{'value':'<p>This is a new page</p>','representation':'storage'}}}";
```