# How to create new page as first child of a specific parent in Confluence using their REST API?

Tags: rest, api, confluence, confluence-rest-api

It is quite simple to automatically create a new page in confluence by using the REST API ([How to create new page in Confluence using their REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523705/how-to-create-new-page-in-confluence-using-their-rest-api#23526357)).

However this adds the newly generated site to the bottom of the page hierarchy/Page navigation, like so:

```
+ Reports
    + Report for January
    + Report for February
    + Report for MARCH
    + NEWLY ADDED REPORT for APRIL
```

Still, it would be preferable to have the reports the other way round (the newest report is more important then the older ones, so it should come first):

```
+ Reports
    + NEWLY ADDED REPORT for APRIL
    + Report for MARCH
    + Report for February
    + Report for January
```

Of course it is possible to move reports around (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/In-Confluence-how-can-I-reverse-the-order-of-our-Meeting-Notes/qaq-p/385516), but I'm now looking for a way to automate this. So I'm searching for one of the following:

- A JSON parameter that could be added to the REST call that creates the new page with the report - and that allows me to specify that the page should be added in the beginning and not to the end. (Preferred way)
- A REST command that allows me to do (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/In-Confluence-how-can-I-reverse-the-order-of-our-Meeting-Notes/qaq-p/385516) autonomously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, finally found out how this works. In case someone has a similar problem:

```
curl -X GET "https://confluenceServer/pages/movepage.action?pageId=TheIdOfThePageToMove&position=above&targetId=idOfOtherPage" -H "authorization: Basic base64encodedUsernameAndPassword" -H "x-atlassian-token: no-check"
```